# Two mods use different versions of the same DLL. Which one do I use?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I'm setting up (another) modded install of KSP, and I'm including both the [B9 Aerospace pack](http://kerbalspaceport.com/0-19-1-b9-aerospace-pack-release-2/) and the [Firespitter airplane parts pack](http://kerbalspaceport.com/firespitter-propeller-plane-parts/). However, they both use Firespitter.dll in order for some of the internal views to have functional components.  Unfortunately, the DLLs are different between the two mods, and I can't see any indication of which one to use.  Are the two functionally identical?  Will one work for both parts packs?

Comment: Are the Firesplitter.dll s the same size?

Comment: @RavenDreamer: No they are not.  If they were, and the modified date were the same, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Then it's likely the mods are incompatible with each other. You won't be able to use them both without errors, if at all.

Comment: So I just tried twice to start KSP, and while it boots, I can't actually get into the game beyond the title screen.  I suspect this is when plugin DLLs are loaded, and I currently have both (one renamed) in the plugins folder.  Previously, I did have both packs installed, but only one DLL (the "newer" and larger one) in the folder, but I also saw some [strange things](http://youtu.be/oAzLR7BxAC0) that I attributed to another plugin.

Comment: So I may have been partially wrong before.  I can get into the game, but it takes a while to do so.  As stated, this may be because of the number of plugin based mods I have for this install.

Comment: I guess/hope/believe this is now obsolete after the restructuring of the GameData and Plugins directories.

Comment: @FEichinger: Nope, B9 still puts its version of Firespitter.dll in the Firespitter folder.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell what you're normally supposed to do, but I installed the Firespitter pack first, and then the B9 Aerospace pack. I chose to overwrite all existing files and it's working for me.

Comment: I would add that, being the Firespitter Airplane Parts the mod actually owning the plugin, it would be updated with the mod, and if it was updated, it would probably be because of added functionality, so the mod is probably not going to work with an older version. Vice-versa, as B9 is just using the plugin, probably it can work with a more updated version of the same.